# css-mode remove dashes from prefix properites in Emacs

Tags: css, emacs, elisp

If I have css that have prefixed properties like:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
```

when I put cursor at the begining and reindent using <kbd>TAB</kbd> Emacs remove leading dash.

```
moz-border-radius: 10px;
```

**Is there a way to remove this bug or feature?**

My config for css-mode look like this:

```
(defun str-repeat (str n)
  (apply 'concat (make-list n str)))

(define-skeleton cssm-insert-curlies
  "foo" nil
  "{\n" (str-repeat " " cssm-indent-level) _ "\n}")


(setq cssm-indent-level 4)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
(setq cssm-indent-function  #'cssm-c-style-indenter)
(setq cssm-newline-before-closing-bracket t)
```

Comment: Which CSS mode is this?  The one that comes with Emacs doesn't seem to have variables starting with `cssm`.

Comment: @legoscia I'm using css-mode v. 0.11 by Lars Marius Garshol, didn't know that emacs have builtin css-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is from line 274

```
; Remove all leading whitespace on this line (
  (if (not (or (null pos)
       (= beg-of-line start)))
  (kill-region beg-of-line start))
```

Don't understand which way it should work there, so don't have a fix. Why not use the shipped css-mode? BTW there will be other css-modes around, should you miss something.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I was able to fix it by adding `\-` to the regex: `(pos (re-search-forward "[]@#a-zA-Z0-9;,.\"{}/*\n:[\-]" (point-max) t))` in line 270

Comment: @jcubic Glad it was useful though :)